# Python - Pygame - Handling angles and speeds of animations

Tags: python, animation, 2d, pygame

I'm learning Pygame, and like most people (I think) am writing a little game to get a handle on it. That being said, feel free to answer my questions as well as critique anything else if it sucks.

So, the issue is with my "boss" object. It's supposed to drop into the game from above, and then start firing a random number of shots in a 360deg circle. It works sometimes, but I am noticing a few things going on that I didn't expect. 1) The bullets should be moving at a constant speed, but they seem to slow down over time, and move faster along the Y plane than the X. 2) Despite there being minimum 8 shots, I often only see 3-4 (pretty sure some are overlapping as I often see one shot that looks a little bigger), and some will shoot down and to the right and one will shoot in the opposite direction. It shouldn't do that. So, here's the code. I'll post the shooting calculations, and then the bullet (Fireball) instance.  The rest is pretty typical from what I've seen. I update and draw by calling the sprite group they're in, which are called at the bottom of my main loop.

```
def shoot (self, shots, time_passed):

    angle = (math.pi*2)/shots
    for i in xrange(shots):
        bullet = Fireball("fireball.png", self.direction, 100)
        bullet.angle = angle
        bullet.pos = ((math.sin(bullet.angle) * bullet.speed) * time_passed,
                      (math.cos(bullet.angle) * bullet.speed) * time_passed)
        Fireball.container.remove(bullet)
        EnemyFireball.container.add(bullet)
        bullet.rect.center = self.rect.center
        angle += angle
```

And this is the bullet:

```
class Fireball (pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    container = pygame.sprite.Group()

    def __init__ (self, image, direction, speed):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__ (self, self.container)

        self.image = pygame.image.load(image).convert_alpha()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.radias = ((self.rect.width/2 + self.rect.height/2)/2)
        self.speed = speed
        self.direction = direction
        self.angle = -1

    def update (self, time_passed):

        if self.angle != -1:
            self.rect.move_ip(self.pos)
        else:
            self.rect.move_ip(0, (self.speed*time_passed) * self.direction)
        if self.rect.bottom < 0: self.kill()
        if self.rect.top > 2000: self.kill()
```

If I may draw a picture...  0 <-- boss, and lines for bullets.

What I expect:

```
\|/  
-0-  
/|\
```

What I am seeing:

```
\  
 0-  
 |\
```

... and the bullet down straight down always looks larger, so I think there's some overlapping, but I can't see why.  Time_passed is just the time calculated between Clock.tick(60), and the shots argument is a randint between 8-16.

I hope that all makes sense. If not, let me know. I'll try to clarify.  Thanks in advance for the help.

Here's a link to the the source if more context is needed. Don't worry, there's not much. http://code.google.com/p/scroller-practice/source/browse/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to keep angle in two variables.

The right way to do it would be

```
curr_angle = 0
angle_step = (math.pi*2)/shots
```

and then at the end of each loop

```
curr_angle += angle_step
```

the way you do it, you end up with angles angle, then 2*angle, then 4*angle and so forth.

if you take away all the other parts and just have a loop that is

```
angle = (math.pi*2)/shots
for i in xrange(shots):
    angle += angle
```

it should be clear that you're doubling angle each time instead of incrementing it.

Comment: This is correct. `angle += angle` ends up being identical to `angle *= 2` (or `angle = angle+angle`, or `angle = angle * 2`), and this surely is not the intended behaviour. By your figure, we see the first few increments being 45°, then 90°, then 180°, and then integer multiples of 360°, which then fall always in the same position, probably causing the "thickening" the OP mentions.

Comment: Haha!  Oh wow. How did I miss that. Thanks so much for pointing that out!  I'm still curious about the slowdown however. The shots along the X plane move slower than those more on the Y plane. So, straight down/up goes fast, left and right go slow. Any thoughts?

Comment: I have a possible theory (but it's a guess): you have positions written as "(math.sin(bullet.angle) * bullet.speed) * time_passed", not as "orig_pos + (math.sin(bullet.angle) * bullet.speed) * time_passed" is it possible that the speed of the parent object is effecting the speed of the shots?